# Proof that $\sup\limits_{x\in X}f(x) - \inf\limits_{x\in X}f(x) = \sup\limits_{x_1,x_2\in X}\left( f(x_1) - f(x_2)\right)$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove following equation

$\sup\limits_{x\in X}f(x) - \inf\limits_{x\in X}f(x) = \sup\limits_{x_1,x_2\in X}\left( f(x_1) - f(x_2)\right)$.

Where $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded function.

Any feedback is welcome for my analysis below.

Let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ be bounded function.

Let least upper bound be $M$. Note that $M \in \mathbb{R}$.
Since $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ then $\forall \varepsilon>0$ we find \emph{only one} $ x_0 \text{ such that } f(x_0) > M- \varepsilon $.
Hence $\forall \;x\in X\setminus{\{x_0\}}\quad f(x) < M$.

Analogically, we have $x_1\in X:\;f(x_1) < m + \varepsilon$, where $m$ is greatest lower bound.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. What is the part you are trying to prove? What part are you assuming to be true? Please edit your question to make this clear.

Comment: @5xum I'm trying to prove first equation. I analyzed it in block which is below 'Any weedback is welcome.'

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is OK. To complete the proof note that $M-m <f(x_0)+\epsilon -(f(x_1)-\epsilon)$ which is at most RHS $+2\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon $ is arbitrary we ger LHS $\leq $RHS. On the other hand LHS $\geq f(x_1)-f(x_2)$ for all $x_1, x_2$ so LHS $\geq$ RHS.